# Cryptographic operations for NISTP256 can be implemented using montgomery method?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I need to implement cryptographic operations starting with the curve NISTP256. I have been told to implement it using Montgomery method. I read a pfd from http://saluc.engr.uconn.edu/refs/sidechannel/okeya00elliptic.pdf. It states that the order of the curve must be divisible by 4. But the curve's order is not a multiple of 4.

So does that mean the curve cannot be implemented using Montgomery method or is there any other ways to implement it?

Comment: Probably your instructor (?) didn't mean the Montgomery Ladder (point multiplication algorithm) but the Montgomery method(s) for large integer arithmetic. See [the HAC](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf) for reference.

Comment: The Montgomery ladder [does exist for any group](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-36400-5_22). What is not doable is to work with P-256 in Montgomery coordinates, since as @abejoe correctly points out, Montgomery curves are necessarily of order divisible by 4.

Comment: @SamuelNeves   Thank you for your information. Hence I conclude that P-256 curves cannot be implemented using Montgomery method.